# Text stops wrapping when put on a background Image in react-native

Tags: user-interface, layout, react-native, word-wrap

For some reason when I put Text inside Image it stops wrapping. I've tried `flexWrap: 'wrap'` but it doesn't help.

Here is how it looks like

[image]

If I put the Text outside of Image than it works OK.

Here is the code:

```
class wraptest extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      source={require('./image.jpg')}
      style={styles.image}>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Text goes here.</Text>
      </View>
    </Image>
  </View>
);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});
```

I've also pushed full project here https://github.com/OleksandrBezhan/react-native-text-wrap-test

Answer (score 0):

The reason the text wraps when it is outside of the image is because it is a direct child of the "container" style which defines the flex box.  Try putting `flex: 1` on either the `textContainer` or `text` styles.